# What is the difference between merge and mergeAll?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

What is the difference between merge and mergeAll? They both seem identical to me:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeAll
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-merge

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[merge](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge) is a static creation method that flattens group of observable.
according to the docs

> Flattens multiple Observables together by blending their values into one Observable.

[image: merge]

simply it will take a group of observables, and flattens them within one, so whenever any observable emits a value, the output will emit a value.

[mergeAll](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeAll) However is different, it is an instance method that works with higher order observables (an observable that emits observables), according to docs

> Converts a higher-order Observable into a first-order Observable which concurrently delivers all values that are emitted on the inner Observables.
>   [image]

I think that sums it up, but mergeAll can be confusing, so let's look at this example provided by rxjs docs

```
import { fromEvent, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { take, map, mergeAll } from 'rxjs/operators';

const higherOrder = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
  map((ev) => interval(1000).pipe(take(10))),
);
const firstOrder = higherOrder.pipe(mergeAll(2));
firstOrder.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

you have a document click observable (higher order) which return an interval observable (inner observable) that emits a value every second, it will complete after 10 intervals emits, which means every time you click on the document, a new interval will be returned, here where merge all comes in, it will subscribe to these intervals returned by the higher order observable, and flattens them into one observable, the first order observable, the argument 2, is to limit to 2 concurrent intervals at a time, so if you clicked 3 times, only 2 will run, but since these 2 intervals will complete after 10 seconds, then  you can click again and mergeAll will subscribe to the new intervals.

Comment: So, are you saying the difference between them is that merge has to be used with observables that emit values and mergeAll has to be used with observables that emit other observables?
And mergeAll will flatten both the inner and outer observables so the outputs are values rather than observables?

Comment: merge doesn't care whatever the observable return, it just groups few observables within one observable, mergeAll merges n* inner observables emitted by ONE higher order observable, and flattens them into one output observable as the example shows.

Answer (score 8):

Both `merge` and `mergeAll` *inherit* from `mergeMap` !

### mergeAll

`mergeAll` is the same as calling `mergeMap` with an **identity function**(`const identity = x => x`)

```js
mergeAll() === mergeMap(obs$ => obs$)
```

Example:

```js
of(a$, b$, c$)
  .pipe(
    mergeAll(),
  )
  .subscribe()

// Same as
of(a$, b$, c$)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(obs$ => obs$)
  )
  .subscribe()
```

Both will subscribe to the incoming observables(`a$`, `b$` and `c$`) and will pass along to their values to the data consumer. Thus, `a$`, `b$` and `c$` are considered **inner observables**.

### merge

Armed with the knowledge from the previous section, understanding `merge` should not be difficult.

`merge(a$, b$, c$).subscribe()` is essentially the same as

```js
const observables = [a$, b$, c$];

new Observable(subscriber => {
  for (let i = 0; i < observables.length; i++) {
    subscriber.next(observables[i]);
  }

  subscriber.complete();
}).pipe(
  mergeAll()
).subscribe();
```